# Writing a nested for loop in Python shell using a line continuation character

Tags: python

I tried to write a nested loop in a Python shell but got a syntax error after entering the second line:

```
for i in range(3):\
    for j in range(3):\
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Remove `backslach` after your `for` loops.

Comment: Remove backslashes. When you add the colon, it adds `...` - now you can indent 4 spaces and do the next loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write `for` loops in the Python shell, you need to press `Shift+Enter` to insert a new line and remove the backslashes, because that will affect the syntax of the code that you are writing. Also, you will have to manually indent your code, adding the necessary spaces to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. The part I was writing after backslash was just a continuation of the first line, as if everything were written on a single line, correct?